# how to add same xml code Automatically inside xml tags?

Tags: swift, xml-parsing

I want to add following xml **code** in my xml file, inside Button tags **automatically**, how can I do that?

**code that I want to add is:**

`customClass="customSearchControl" customModule="IBComponents" customModuleProvider="target"`

**Tags that I want to be edited is**

```
<button>
```

**My expected output is as follow**

```
<button customClass="AmazingButton" customModule="IBComponents" customModuleProvider="target">
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve that in pure Swift or are you on iOS / macOS? If you are on macOS you might want to look into Foundation's [XML Processing and Modeling](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/xml_processing_and_modeling)

Comment: yeah I'm on macOS. but this link was not very helpful.

Comment: I've added sample code on how to add your custom attributes to the button elements of a document. On second thought I'm not sure if this is what you wanted, though. Do you want to edit existing button elements or do you want to create and add button new elements with those attributes to the XML document?

Comment: I want to add attributes to existing as well as newly added buttons automatically.

Comment: Is there any way of making a custom class as a default class for all UIButtons (UIButtons that are already in project and that might be added in future)?
suppose user adds a new button, its default class should be my defined class named as customClass

Comment: See my answer below for editing all button elements in an XML document. I think the topic of modifying Xcode project files might be beyond the scope of this question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on OS X, you have `XMLDocument` at your disposal. iOS doesn't have this class.

```
let xmlString = """
<data>
    <button/>
    <tag>
        <button/>
    </tag>
</data>
"""

let document = try XMLDocument(xmlString: xmlString, options: [.documentTidyXML])
for node in try document.nodes(forXPath: "//button") {
    guard let buttonElement = node as? XMLElement else { continue }

    buttonElement.setAttributesWith([
        "customClass": "AmazingButton",
        "customModule": "IBComponents",
        "customModuleProvider": "target",
    ])
}

let newXMLString = document.xmlString(options: [.nodePrettyPrint])
print(newXMLString)
```

Comment: Note that this code will add the custom attributes to the first child without checking whether it is a button or not.

Comment: I want to add custom attributes to all button tags inside my xml file, how can I do that?

Comment: How can I add attributes to all existing buttons automatically?

Comment: You simply loop through all the buttons that matches an XPath selector. See my edited answer.

Comment: thanks Buddy, problem was solved !!!

Answer (score 1):

On macOS you can use [Foundation's XML processing API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/xml_processing_and_modeling) to parse and modify XML documents:

```
// XML document that we want to modify
let xml = "<foo><button/></foo>"

// Parse XML document
guard let document = try? XMLDocument(xmlString: xml, options: .documentValidate) else {
    return
}

// Find all the buttons
let buttons = try? document.nodes(forXPath: "//button")

// Modify the buttons by adding custom attributes
buttons?.compactMap({ $0 as? XMLElement }).forEach {
    $0.setAttributesWith([
        "customClass": "AmazingButton",
        "customModule": "IBComponents",
        "customModuleProvider": "target"
    ])
}

// Print modified XML document
print(document.xmlString)
```

This prints:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo><button customModuleProvider="target" customModule="IBComponents" customClass="AmazingButton"></button></foo>
```

Which seems like what you were looking for. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: how can I give path of xml file?
I am trying to add custom attributes to main Storyboard xml, how will I provide path ?

Comment: `XMLDocument` as an [initializer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/xmldocument/1418467-init) that takes a `URL` as parameter. This is how you can provide the path of the file containing the XML document you want to modify.

Comment: Thank You Soo much
You made my day @dnlggr

Comment: I see that you changed the accepted answer (which is totally fine of course). I was just wondering for myself if there is there anything still unclear that I could improve in the answer / make clearer in future answers.

Comment: Everything is clear and done, I was marking both answers as accepted :D

Comment: Ok great to hear! :) By the way: you can [only mark one answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40200/can-i-accept-two-answers) as accepted.

Comment: is there a way to run this code automatically when user drag and drop a new button?

Answer (score 0):

```
<button customClass="AmazingButton" customModule="IBComponents" customModuleProvider="target" />
```

The element needs to start and end with the same tag, unless it is not a block element, in this case you end it with /> and it works like a charm.

Comment: oops
it's not the problem that how a tag ends, problem is, I want to add custom attributes as shown in above code, inside a tag <button custom-attribute="value"> like so... I want to do this whole process automatically.....